# MySQL query custom sorting from function

Tags: mysql

Lets say i have a table that has the following field names

```
'id' 'likes' 'rating' 'view'
```

A normal MySQL sort would require a simple

```
SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY likes DESC, rating DESC, view DESC
```

Now lets say I would want to order the given entries in my table by an arbitrary function

```
function custom_sort(likes, rating, view) {
    fame = 0.5 * like + 0.25 * rating - view;
    return fame;
}
```

I want to know if it is possible to do this pseudo code like action

```
 SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY custom_sort(likes, rating, view) DESC
```

Comment: You even can do it without any functions, just write all this (I mean `0.5 * like + 0.25 * rating - view`) in ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply...

```
SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY ( 0.5 * likes + 0.25 * rating - view ) DESC
```

Comment: this only works if you use normal math operators like +-/* but what about php functions like min/max?

Comment: @toxicate20 Yes, but you should not confuse these functions with the aggregate ones. For example, you can write something like... `0.5 * LEAST(likes, 0.5)` in your `ORDER BY` expression just fine.